# javascript: pass local variables to anonymous function

Tags: javascript

**Question:** how to access `shortcut` or `action` or other local variables

**Related:** Similar questions but not success:

- [Passing local variable to loader anonymous handler function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7860100/1290995)
- [how to pass local variables when assigning mouseover via anonymous
  function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1140973/1290995)
- [javascript anonymous function parameter passing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6188861/1290995)
- [How to pass variable to anonymous function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10207556/1290995)

**Java Solution:**
set `final` modifier to variables that required in anonymous function

**Target Source code:**

```
//plugin.buttons is collection of button objects
for (var i in plugin.buttons) {
    var button = plugin.buttons[i];
    var icon = button.icon;
    var text = button.text;
    var shortcut = button.shortcut;
    var action = button.action; //action is a function ( or method )

    if (shortcut != null && shortcut.length > 0) {
        if ($.isFunction(action)) {
            console.log(shortcut); //it's valid shortcut
            //using jQuery hotkey plugin
            $('div[contenteditable]').bind('keydown', shortcut, function () {
                console.log(shortcut); //it's undefined
                action.call(); //it's undefined also
                return false;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it should just work as shown since JS can reach those vars via closure...  EDIT: whoops, wrap your for loop in a function, the oldest major workaround for lack of loop scope in the book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass it in as [**event data**](http://api.jquery.com/event.data/)

```
for (var i in plugin.buttons) {
    var button = plugin.buttons[i];
    var icon = button.icon;
    var text = button.text;
    var shortcut = button.shortcut;
    var action = button.action; //action is a function ( or method )

    if (shortcut != null && shortcut.length > 0) {
        if ($.isFunction(action)) {

            $('div[contenteditable]').on('keydown', {shortcut : shortcut}, function (e) {

                console.log(e.data.shortcut);

            });
        }
    }
}
```

But in this case the real issue is that there is no special scope in a for loop, so defining variables inside the for loop just overwrites the same variables on each iteration, which is why it doesn't work when the event handler is called at a later time.

You have to lock in the variable in a new scope

```
for (var key in plugin.buttons) {
    (function(i) {
        var button = plugin.buttons[i];
        var icon = button.icon;
        var text = button.text;
        var shortcut = button.shortcut;
        var action = button.action; //action is a function ( or method )

        if (shortcut != null && shortcut.length > 0) {
            if ($.isFunction(action)) {
                console.log(shortcut); //it's valid shortcut
                //using jQuery hotkey plugin
                $('div[contenteditable]').bind('keydown', shortcut, function () {
                    console.log(shortcut); //it's undefined
                    action.call(); //it's undefined also
                    return false;
                });
            }
        }
    })(key);
}
```

Comment: what about the for-loop non-scope thingy ?

Comment: @dandavis - Oh, you're right, there's no scope in a for loop, so the variables are overwritten on each iteration. Passing them as event data would solve that, but an IIFE would be more approriate, changing this answer now.

Comment: your first answer doesn't work for me because second parameter must be a string to work with jQuery Hotkey. But your second answer is nice solution and worked well! thanks.